# Orchard Core CMS - Content Versioning, Scheduling and Audit Trail

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcore

We are considering Orchard Core CMS for our needs. There are three features that appear to have been supported in legacy Orchard - the ability to version content, schedule publishing and audit trails, but none of these appear to be available in Orchard Core CMS OOB.

How can functionality for the three features be accomplished in Orchard Core? Would they have to be done through the use of workflows or custom modules? Any insight into whether these features are on the roadmap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

- Content versioning is available in Orchard, when you publish a draftable content item it'll create a new version. There is just no UI for this yet but we actually have an [Audit Trail module](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/issues/4620) ready behind the scenes and working on open-sourcing it. This offers full audit trail capabilities similar to Orchard 1, as well as the ability to browse and restore previous versions.
- [Scheduled publishing](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/issues/3991) is done and the pull request awaits merging.

Answer (score 0):

Received this response from Sebastian Ros, one of the key contributors to Orchard Core. As of the time of writing:

```
Content versioning is already implemented. There is no UI to list previous versions right now. There is an issue filed to track it.
Scheduled publishing can already be implemented using workflows, but there is an issue to track a more integrated solution, like in O1.
Audit trails is on the roadmap but not yet started.

1.0 will be shipped when all issues currently tagged with 1.0 and P0,P1,P2 flags have been implemented.
```

https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/issues/5597